# MS Access Unique Constraint with more than 10 fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I know that this is a limitation of Access, but does anyone know of a good workaround that would allow me to avoid duplicate records in a situation where my table has 30 fields and I don't want any duplicate combinations of those 30 fields?

I'm basically batch loading financial data on a regular basis and I only want to add records if some of the information for a particular project id has changed since the last load.  When I run the append query that adds new records I was hoping to use the constraint to block the inserts, but trying to figure out another solution.

Comment: The project id is a foreign key because the project can have various combinations of other attributes on this table (also foreign keys mostly) and is therefore not unique. But yes, it is present on the table and the data is coming from a an Access staging table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only insert the non-duplicating records, you need to filter out the duplicate ones in the query with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` subquery, like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO tTgt (project_id, field1, ..., field30)
SELECT project_id, field1, ..., field30
FROM tSrc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT project_id 
    FROM tTgt
    WHERE tTgt.project_id = tSrc.project_id
      AND tTgt.field1 = tSrc.field1
      ...
      AND tTgt.field30 = tSrc.field30
    )
```

The subquery will be rather lengthy, but in the end it's the same work that an index would have to do.

Comment: thanks Andre! That seems like it will work..I will give it a shot.  Is the "SELECT project_id" after the WHERE NOT EXISTS somewhat arbitrary in terms of only selecting the project_id field from the target table or is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: @Scott: Ha, spot on question. The most obvious thing would be a `SELECT *` instead, because we simply want to know if a record exists or not. But I think (but am not sure) that selecting only one field (an id seems appropriate) is more efficient.

Comment: ok, yes makes sense.  I'm hoping Access isn't going to choke on this, but we shall see.  Typically trying to load in a few thousand records so will see..thanks again!

Comment: Beware if any of field1 thru field30 contain Null, the `NOT EXISTS` will be evaluated as True, which means that tSrc row be added to tTgt regardless of whether or not tTgt already contains an exact copy.

Comment: ok thanks Hans.  All of the fields are foreign keys except three which are Boolean.  I assume when these are false they get evaluated as 0 and not NULL?

Comment: Right, False = 0 and an Access Yes/No field can not be Null.

Comment: Well...it actually worked and it was pretty damn efficient on top of it.  Evaluated 2200 records in less than 5 seconds. Cheers!